# Replace " within a character vector

Tags: r, string, character

I have data in a character column that includes " characters. For example:

```
258
"6,962.30"
96
```

I am trying to clean this column with to make it numeric.

The command:

```
df$Column <-sub(' .*"','',df$Column)
```

Is not working. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `sub` with a character class:

```r
x <- c(258, '"6,962.30"', 96)
output <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]+", "", x))
output

[1]  258.0 6962.3   96.0
```

Comment: Learned about character classes! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readr::parse_number`.

```
df$Column <- readr::parse_number(df$Column)
```

For example,

```
x <- c(258, '"6,962.30"', 96)
readr::parse_number(x)
#[1]  258.0 6962.3   96.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd just need to substitute comma.

```
as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$Column))
# [1]  258.0 6962.3   96.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R approach:

```
as.numeric(gsub('\\"|,','',v))
[1]  258.0 6962.3   96.0
```